# Java decode special characters Â¡ and Ì§ becomes A?¡ and I?§

Tags: java, xml, special-characters, decode

I'm trying to read a file name off XML, whose encoding can be changed.

The file name on the XML has string such as "I&#768;&#167;oI&#768;" which is supposed to be read by my code as "Ì§oÌ". However, I keep getting I?§.

Similar problem for Â and A?¡

Below is my code:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
ByteArrayInputStream bAis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, rlen);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( hbis, "ISO-8859-1" ));
String theStringINeed = bReader.readLine();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't reading that as XML.

Comment: How are you inspecting the string?

Comment: Are you asking about the _filename_ or the result of parsing the files.

Answer (score 2):

```
new InputStreamReader( hbis, "ISO-8859-1" )
```

If you lie about the encoding of a file, bad things will happen.

You need to read the file using the encoding it was actually written in, which is probably UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but what if I do not know the original encoding of the filename? All I can tell is whatever the name's manifested in windows directory?

Comment: @Arzath: Then you have a difficult problem.  What exactly are these bytes coming from?

Comment: They are files names that are read off files in a folder, and programmatically coded to a xml file. The xml file is then served to the socket. Hope that is not confusing.

Comment: Also, "programmatically" means using XmlSerializer.text("filename")